# Error when Overriding method from MediaPlayerEventAdapter VLCj

Tags: java, overriding, vlcj

I am using an EmbeddedMediaPlayer object to read video files. What I want is to know when the video is done playing so I need an Event listener. 
The MediaPlayerEventListener and MediaPlayerEventAdapter have a finished() method.
But when I try to override the method, the following error comes up:

```
The method finished(MediaPlayer) of type new MediaPlayerEventAdapter(){} must override or implement a supertype method.
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
private void registerListeners()
{
    mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
            avatarplayerappInstance.playDoneHandler();
        }

    });
}
```

Do you have any idea of how I can solve that issue ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should show the definition of the `MediaPlayerEventAdapter` class **you are using**.

Comment: You can see [these examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter). You seem to do things right here. Maybe the problem is before you implement the `Listener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error is triggered when the arguments of the method are not matching the method definition ones.

Here, `MediaPlayer` should be imported from the same package as `MediaPlayerEventAdapter`.

Make sure you imported these:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer; 
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
```